# Better method for enforcing ASCII characters on attribute strings

Tags: python, encoding, ascii

I have a method of stripping string characters not in ASCII[0:126] for all string attributes of an object:

```
def niceEncoding(string):
    new = ''
    #matches all printable ascii characters (0 to 126)
    n = re.compile("[ -~]")
    for char in n.findall(string):
        new += char
    return new

def cleanObjEncodings(obj):
    for k, v in vars(obj).items():
        if type(v) is str:
            setattr(obj, k, niceEncoding(v))
    return obj
```

Do people have ideas about a more efficient method?

//

Improved method chosen (thanks):

```
non_printable = re.compile("[^ -~]")

def cleanObjEncodings(obj):
    for k, v in vars(obj).items():
        if type(v) is str:
            setattr(obj, k, non_printable.sub('', v))
    return obj
```

Comment: Consider using `list.join` instead of building incrementally larger strings with `+=`.

Comment: Isn't space ASCII character 32 (not 0)? So in your comment "printable ascii characters (0 to 126)", either "printable" or "0" is wrong

Comment: I mean ASCII characters from the space to the tilde.

Comment: For instance I want to remove any character that doesn't match the regex [ -~], for instance: ° (ASCII 248)

Comment: Just to be pedantic, anything greater than 127 is not ASCII. It's part of some other character set that's a superset of ASCII, of which there are many.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about just inverting the sense of your regular expression? Instead of matching the *good* characters, match the *bad* ones and replace them each with an empty string.

The code becomes even cleaner if you separate out the building of the regular expression, which only needs to occur once.

```
#matches all except printable ascii characters (32 to 126)
re_non_printable = re.compile("[^ -~]")

def niceEncoding(string):
    return re_non_printable.sub("", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Emphasizing readability:

```
from string import printable
def niceEncoding(str):
    printable_characters = frozenset(printable)
    return ''.join(c for c in str if c in printable_characters)
```

A probably faster (I have not actually profiled) but less readable approach:

```
def niceEncoding(str):
    unprintable_characters = ''.join(chr(i) for i in (range(0, 32) + range(127, 256)))
    return str.translate(None, unprintable_characters)
```